# How to join Non-Spatial table to Spatial table in Postgis database (Both tables are in different database)

Tags: postgresql, join, postgis, postgresql-8.4

I need to join a Non-spatial table to Spatial table, but both are in different database.

```
Spatial_table(dbname:dist)
gid
district_name
district_code
geom
```

```
Non_Spatial(dbname:census)
ID
district_code
population
male_popu
female_popu
```

Can anyone please suggest me, How to relate the above to tables to get the query result for the population of specific district?

Also can anyone tell me about the difference between Joining and Relating of two tables.

Comment: Well, you have `distric_code` in both tables. It doesn't make any difference for the DB if it's spatial or not. Just join them toghether as you would with any other table.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30519/how-to-relate-non-spatial-table-to-spatial-table-in-two-different-postgis-dbs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a cross-database join in PostgreSQL. The way MySQL uses databases PostgreSQL uses schemas.

There is an add-on called [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/dblink.html) though which lets you query another PG database (even on another machine).

That's not going to be very efficient with a join though, because it's going to have to transfer a whole table in one direction or the other to do the comparisons. If you are going to regularly want to join tables they need to be in the same database (but perhaps separate schemas).